# Multipart Returns Bytes or InputStream not sure how to upload it to FTP server

Tags: spring-integration

Below is the code where we have multipart object - which will have either bytes or input stream

```java
    Map<String, MultipartFile> multipartRequestParams = request.getFileMap();
    MultipartFile multipartFile = multipartRequestParams.get("file");
    multipartFile.getBytes() (or) multipartFile.getInputStream
```

How to define a gateway for this and send the file

```java
     gateway.upload(multipartFile.getBytes(), multipartFile.getOriginalFilename(), remoteDirectory); 

        @MessagingGateway
    public interface UploadGateway {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannel")
        void upload(@Payload byte[] file, @Header("filename") String filename, @Header("path") String path);
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler toHandler() {
    ....
    ....
    }
```

I'm confused how to send this file to the SFTP server via which mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> multipartFile.getBytes() (or) multipartFile.getInputStream

That's not true. The byte array in this case is really extracted from that `InputStream`. So, according your description both of them are present at the same time.

The rest of your code is OK. That's is fully correct to have a byte arrays (or that file `InputStream`) as a `@Payload` and other useful data as `@Header`.

To transfer that data into SFTP you should use an `SftpMessageHandler`, which support both `byte[]` and `InputStream` as a payload of request message from that `toSftpChannel`. See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound.

The `filename` header could be used from the `setFileNameGenerator(FileNameGenerator fileNameGenerator)` option of that `SftpMessageHandler`. You just take this header from a message provided for that `FileNameGenerator` contract.

Similar could be done for the `path` header, which, essentially, should lend in the `setRemoteDirectoryExpressionString(String remoteDirectoryExpression)` option, like this `setRemoteDirectoryExpressionString("headers.path")`.

All that info is present in the mentioned docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot but can you please show me some code which deals without XML i.e with annotation. I'm looking for the java code instead of xml file. Can you share me one code snippet or a link

Comment: The documentation I shared in the answer has a Java Configuration section: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#configuring-with-java-configuration-2.

Comment: The only problem which i have is how to pass the byte[] or the inputstream. Do i need to explicitly use put command in outbound gateway ? The message handler doesn't process the stream or bytes which were the confusion is

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. The docs for `SftpMessageHandler` starts from the description what type of payload is supported in a message you send to the input channel of the endpoint for that handler. See that Java sample in details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#configuring-with-java-configuration-2. It sends a `File` as a payload in a gateway arguments, but that simply can be a `byte[]` or an `InputStream`.

Comment: I saw the above link sends a File Object argument. Can we send any argument such as byte[] or InputStream instead of file such as void sendToSftp(InputStream fileInputStream); or void sendToSftp(byte[] fileBytes);. I'm not sure what the argument will be taken by default as i don't see the method signature of message handler.

Comment: Right. You have a gateway contract with `InputStream` or `byte[]`. That argument is going to be a `payload` of a message arriving to the `SftpMessageHandler`. That one takes this message gets its payload and check its type for respective internal logic. If you wish, here is a source code of the `RemoteFileTemplate` used in that  `SftpMessageHandler`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/remote/RemoteFileTemplate.java#L490-L532

Comment: Nice...Very Good..Most appreciatable...Thanks a lot...